# TreeView Item - Hierarchichal Data Template with Combo

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, treeview

I have an edit template for a radtreeview control.  i'd like to add a combo (dropdown) inside the edit template and have it populated.  i'm stuck in the part as to how to get the combo populated with data.  i can't reference the combo control as it is inside a template so in theory does not exist until the item gets selected.  i tried using a binding expression back to my view model but that does not seem to work.

should the binding work to populate a combo inside a template?

Cheers,
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the edit template but I've used an ItemTemplate for the RadTreeView with something similar to this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboData}" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

So the ComboBox binds to the enumerable ComboData which exists at the same level as the Name property.